Linear algebra question about span
Prove or disprove the following.
If S1 and S2 are arbitrary subsets of a vector space V , then the intersection of their spans
(⟨S1⟩ ∩ ⟨S2⟩) equals the span of their intersection (⟨S1 ∩ S2⟩) .

See the duplicate for a counterexample.
